# Significance of $c$ squared in Einstein energy mass formula

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass-energy

It is general experience that quantities related with phenomenon come in its mathematical formulation. 
Then how is $c$ squared involved in mathematical relationship between mass and energy as given by Einstein 
$E = m c^2$?